# How to plot Sensitivity/Specificity curve (link for example image below) for a binary classifier?

Tags: r, classification, logistic-regression, roc

I have a predicted probability for a binary classifier (Responder vs Non-Responder) along with the Actuals. (classifier which I used is a logistic regression)

Now I want to create the Sensitivity/Specificity plots like in this link.
[Sensitivity/Specificity Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5D9u.jpg)

Another example of Sensitivity/Specificity plot, I am referring to the top-right side first plot:
https://kennis-research.shinyapps.io/ROC-Curves/

I am confused about, what should be my x-axis & y-axis to generate both the bell curves (Responder vs Non-Responder in my case)? Creating these plots in R or Excel should be fine.

Comment: your problem seems to be linked to theory and not programming. Look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Hi Davide, Thanks for the comment. I am kind of new to Stackoverflow, so you want me to post this in stats.StackOverflow since its a theory question?